Multi-language support for MapServer WMS layer legend
I am configuring MapServer WMS layers based on vector data and need to support multiple languages. One problem is the legends, another, not necessarily related, is the capability document, so I'm posting two separate questions. This one is about the legends.
The raster image generated in response to GetLegendGraphic must contain class titles in the language requested by a lang parameter. I prepared the data to contain attributes with the translated class names. How can I achieve a language specific CLASS TITLE, either by a data lookup, or any other mechanism? For labels (CLASS TEXT), expressions can be defined (docs), but not for CLASS TITLE, where I'd like to do something like distinct title_%lang% where category = 5.
Here is a working example from the Swiss Federal Office of Topography swisstopo: https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=ch.astra.wanderland-sperrungen_umleitungen&format=image/png&STYLE=default&lang=fr (compare with lang=de)
